# Deducing type, when using member function pointer as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

When I want to have member function as template argument, is there a way to templetize it without providing `Caller` type?

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename Caller, void (Caller::*Func)(int)>
    void call(Caller * c) { (c->*Func)(6); }
};

struct Bar
{
    void start() 
    {
        Foo f;
        f.call<Bar, &Bar::printNumber>(this);
               ^^^^  
    }

    void printNumber(int i) { std::cout << i; }
};

int main ()
{
    Bar b;
    b.start();
    return 0;
}
```

when I try

```
template <void (Caller::*Func)(int), typename Caller>
void call(Caller * c) { (c->*Func)(6); }
```

and call it like

```
f.call<&Bar::printNumber>(this);
```

I am getting `Caller is not class...` error.

So, is there a way to let compiler deduce the Caller type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not as you want it. `Caller` could be deduced if

1. the pointer to member function were an parameter, not a template parameter. Eg:

   ```
   template <class Caller>
   void call(Caller * c, void (Caller::*Func)(int)) { (c->*Func)(6); }
   ```
2. it was known beforehand. For example, you could make the call look like this:

   ```
   f.arg(this).call<&Bar::printNumber>();
   ```

   The `call` function would look similar to this:

   ```
   template <class Arg>
   struct Binder
   {
     template<void (Arg::*Func)(int)>
     void operator()() const {
       ...
     }
   };
   ```

   The `arg` function would be easy to write (in your case it would return `Binder<Bar>`, where `Bar` is deduced from `this`).

   Not very convenient, IMHO.

Comment: thank you very much! I do not even know why I tried to templetize it instead of regular parameter :) thank you again