# I would like to deduce a type in C++ template, from a pointer to a member function

Tags: c++

*Short version:*

Instead of always having to type:

```
auto function_pointer = &decorator<int, Foo, void &Foo::bar(int)>
```

I would like to be able to just write

```
auto function_pointer = &decorator<void &Foo::bar(int)>
```

where the `int` and `Foo` are automatically extracted from `<void &Foo::bar(int)`>.

---

For starters I have:

```
map<string, Object*> all_object_instances;

class Object {
public:
     Object(const string &name) { all_object_instances[name]=this; }
     virtual ~Object() { all_object_instances.erase(name); }
};

class Foo : public Object {
public:
     Foo(const string &name) : Object(name) {}
     void bar(int);
};
```

I need a function, that will call **Foo::bar(int)** with some decoration, so I write:

```
template <class Arg, class C, void C::*T(Arg)>
void decorator(const string &name, const string &s_arg)
{
    Arg a = my_convert(s_arg);
    C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(all_object_instances[name]);
    (c->*T)(a);
}
```

So my main code has to look like this:

```
   new Foo("MyFoo");
   ....
   auto saved_f = &decorator<int, Foo, void &Foo::bar(int)>;
   ....
   saved_f("MyFoo", "123");
   ....
   delete all_object_instances("MyFoo") // for symmetry
```

It would be a lot better, if I could just have 1 template argument:

```
saved_f = &decorator<void &Foo::bar(int)>;
```

And derive both **'Foo'**, and **'int'** from the argument:

```
template <TEMPLATE MAGIC>
void decorator(const string &name, const string &s_arg)
{
    typedef ARG_MAGIC ARG;
    typedef CLASS_MAGIC C;

    Arg a = my_convert(s_arg);
    C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(all_object_instances[name]);
    (c->*T)(a);
}
```

Does any such thing exist?

Comment: I've edited the question in an attempt to make it much simpler and clearer? Is my 'Short version' correct? If so, you should consider greatly simplifying (or even deleting!) the remainder of your question as it is mostly irrelevant

Comment: yes that is a great revision. I would like to leave the long version, because sometimes my stab at the problem was wrong to begin with :)

Thanks tho

Comment: You can narrow it down to two template parameters if you just supply the member function pointer type, but as far as I can tell, there's [no way to deduce the type of a function pointer template argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736337/is-there-a-way-to-deduce-the-value-of-a-function-pointer-template-parameter). Per that answer, though, you *could* make a macro (I know :/) to expand the arguments into the type, pointer pair you want. After that it's only a matter of [finding the return, class, and argument types.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a577f71af2697f16)

Comment: There's also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10224611/4892076), if you know a bit about the function pointer's type beforehand. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11746632/4892076) is related, too.

Comment: Can you use C++17? I guess you want the member function pointer as template argument instead of as function argument in order to get a "real" function pointer back, i.e. not a closure?

Comment: Yes Daniel, I can neither use c++17 nor get a pointer. The whole thing has to be converted to a simple function call with prefixed arguments. So I am "generating" a wrapper function with templates. 
-
If I could change the infrastructure, I would replace function calls with functional objects, and use bind() or other methods to generate and allocate a functor.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the function as an argument will allow it to be invoked. It can be deduced simply through template argument deduction.

In the below example I've just added a bit of genericity, passing the arguments through `std::invoke`, which can do the automatic pointer-to-member call.

```c++
template<class R,class C,class... Args>
auto get_class_type(R(C::*)(Args...))->C;

template<class F>
auto decorator(F f) {
  return [f=move(f)](auto const& name, auto const& arg) {
    using C=decltype(get_class_type(f));
    return std::invoke(move(f),
      dynamic_cast<C*>(all_object_instances[name]),
      my_convert(arg)
    );
  };
}
```

Now this is reduced to:

```c++
auto saved_f = decorator(&Foo::bar);
saved_f("MyFoo", "123");
```

This requires a C++1y compliant compiler for `std::invoke`, which can be found in `<functional>`. If this doesn't compile for you, simply change it to:

```c++
auto c = dynamic_cast<C*>(all_object_instances[name]);
return (c->*move(f))(my_convert(arg));
```

---

If your goal is to have the template argument be a compile time constant, that is also possible. In this case you will have to use a macro and pass an `integral_constant` to `decorator`:

```c++
#define decorator(mem_f) decorator_impl( integral_constant<decltype( mem_f ), mem_f>{} )
```

Then extract the value out of the type:

```c++
template<class I>
auto decorator_impl( I ) {
  auto constexpr f = I::value;
  // same code as before...
}
```

Comment: interstging, deciphering this. What's this syntax:

  template<class R,class C,class... Args>
  auto get_class_type(R(C::*)(Args...))->C;

I only know of template function, class or using (in c++1x)

Comment: @dandax It's a declaration of a function template. It takes as its argument a pointer to a member function of a class `C`, that takes `Args...` as its parameters and returns the type `R`. I'm simply returning the type of the class `C` (by doing `auto (...) -> C`

Comment: How is that different from:
template<class R,class C,class... Args>
C get_class_type(R(C::*)(Args...));

Comment: @dandax In this case there's absolutely no difference, simply a matter of style.

Answer (score -1):

In c++17, you should be able to write:

```
template <auto m>
void decorator(const string &name, const string &s_arg);
```

with the desired syntax:

```
auto saved_f = &decorator<void &Foo::bar(int)>
```

instead of

```
template <typename M, M m>
void decorator(const string &name, const string &s_arg);
```

with syntax

```
auto saved_f = &decorator<decltype(&Foo::bar), &Foo::bar>;
```

or your version.

Then you need some function traits to retrieve class and return type, something like:

```
template <typename> struct method_traits; 

template <typename Ret, typename Class, typename ... Args>
struct method_traits<Ret (Class::*)(Args...)>
{
    using ret_type = Ret;
    using classe_type = Class;
    using args_type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

And so finally:

```
template <auto m>
void decorator(const string &name, const string &s_arg)
{
    using C = typename method_traits<decltype(m)>::class_type;
    using Arg = std::tuple_element_t<0, typename method_traits<decltype(m)>::args_type>;

    Arg a = my_convert(s_arg);
    C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(all_object_instances[name]);
    (c->*T)(a);
}
```

Comment: Does any compiler support `auto` template parameters in a released version yet? The status is listed as "No" for gcc and "SVN" for clang...

Comment: What does expression `void &Foo::bar(int)` mean?

Comment: How does 'using C = typename method_traits<decltype(m)>::class_type;' work ? implicit args for classes now work in later c++ standards?