# How to deduce type of `T` from a pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a template, more or less like this:

```
template<typename T,void (T::*F)()>
struct Foo{
    /* ... do some stuff with the member function pointer ...*/
    //... e.g.
    T foo(){
        T t;
        t.*F;
        return t;
};
```

it works, but I dont like the way I have to instantiate it:

```
Foo<SomeVeryLongClassName,&SomeVeryLongClassName::AnEvenLongerMemberFunctionName> f;
```

Is there some way I can make the template deduce `T`? 
I was thinking of a template method that I could call like this:

```
getFoo(&SomeVeryLongClassName::AnEvenLongerMemberFunctionName);
```

or, as I will mainly use `Foo` inside `T`, that would be just

```
getFoo(AnEvenLongerMemberFunctionName);
```

I tried this

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T,void (T::*MEMFUN)()>
struct Foo{};

template <typename T,void (T::*MEMFUN)()>
Foo<typename T,typename MEMFUN> getFoo(MEMFUN f){ 
     return Foo<typename T,typename MEMFUN>(); 
}


struct Bar { void test(){ std::cout << "MUH" << std::endl;} };

int main (){ getFoo(&Bar::test); }
```

The error messages are actually quite clear, but I dont understand them at all...

```
templateExample.cpp:9:28: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
 Foo<typename T,typename MEMFUN>
                            ^
templateExample.cpp:4:8: error: provided for ‘template<class T, void (T::* MEMFUN)()> struct Foo’
 struct Foo{
        ^
templateExample.cpp:10:7: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘(’ token
 getFoo(MEMFUN f){
       ^
templateExample.cpp:10:7: error: template declaration of ‘int getFoo’
templateExample.cpp:10:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘f’
 getFoo(MEMFUN f){
               ^
templateExample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
templateExample.cpp:20:20: error: ‘getFoo’ was not declared in this scope
   getFoo(&Bar::test);
```

...why "wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)" ?

How can I help the compiler to deduce `T` when instantiating a `Foo` ?
Is it possible with only pre-C++11?

PS: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366045/i-would-like-to-deduce-a-type-in-c-template-from-a-pointer-to-a-member-functi) is very close to being a dupe, but I really need to know the type of `T` and not just call the member function (e.g. I need to create an instance).

Comment: `MEMFUN` is not a `typename`.

Comment: Is there a reason `F` needs to be a template argument instead of an instance constant? That is, pass `&SomeVeryLongClassName::AnEvenLongerMemberFunctionName` into the constructor for `Foo`, and just templatize the class based on `T`. Then it would be relatively easy to create the `getFoo` method. The issue now is that `getFoo` might be called with a runtime variable, and you can’t turn runtime variables into template parameters.

Comment: @DanielH yes there is a reason, but thats a too long story, sorry ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17 we have non-type template parameters with deduced types:

```
template <auto> struct Foo;

template <typename T, void (T::*MF)()> struct Foo<MF> {
  // ...
};
```

Usage: `Foo<&X::f>`

You can also directly use `template <auto X>` and either keep using `auto` inside your template or use `decltype(X)` to get at the type of the non-type parameter.

---

Prior to C++17, you could try to perform deduction via some contortions involving helper class templates with member function templates and `decltype`.

The gory details:

If you define a function template `template <typename T, void(T::*MF)()> Foo<T, MF> f(MF);`, where Foo is your old-style class template (like `template <typename T, void (T::*MF)()> class Foo;`), then you can use `decltype(f(&X::h))` to deduce the desired type `Foo<X, &X::h>` without having to repeat X. The price is that you either need to say `decltype` everywhere, or you wrap that in a macro.

Comment: `template <auto>` ? omg c++ is getter weirder every day for me. "Let me know if you'd like the gory details" no thanks, I will try to figure out myself and ask in case I dont manage :)

Comment: (@tobi303: a very similar example appeared at the bottom of the changelist in this [blog bost](https://isocpp.org/blog/2017/04/p0636r0-changes-between-cpp14-and-c17-dis-thomas-koeppe).)

Comment: @KerrekSB Gorry details please.

Comment: @Catskul: If you define a function template `template <typename T, void(T::*MF)()> Foo<T, MF> f(MF);`, where `Foo` is your old-style class template (like `template <typename T, void (T::*MF)()> class Foo;`), then you can use `decltype(f(&X::h))` to deduce the desired type `Foo<X, &X::h>` without having to repeat `X`. The price is that you either need to say `decltype` everywhere, or you wrap that in a macro.

Comment: @Kerrek SB sorry to revive this, but would you know how to make the c++17 work in presence of overload sets like X::f and X::f const?