# Deduce Type of Class for std::function Made From A Member Function Pointer

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, pointer-to-member, std-function, type-deduction

There's plenty of examples of deducing the class type of an MFP (member function pointer) ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211811/how-to-deduce-type-of-t-from-a-pointer-to-member-function)). But say I have:

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
    int doSomething(int);
}

int doSomethingElse(MyStruct&,int);

std::function<int(MyStruct&,int)> func1 = &MyStruct::doSomething;
std::function<int(MyStruct&,int)> func2 = &doSomethingElse;
```

I'd like to do some SFINAE based on whether the function was created with an MFP, then use the type of the class with that member function (if it was). However, func1 and func2 appear to have the same type.

I only care about unbound functions so something like `std::function<int(int)> func3 = std::bind(&MyStruct::doSomething, MyStruct(), _1);` isn't important as it is already bound to an object (and seems impossible to differentiate anyways). I was hoping std::function's target/target_type might have something for me but it seems not.

Currently the only solution I can think of is to force a user to use one of two implementations where one assumes that the function was created with an MFP and uses the first parameter type as the class, but I'd like to supply only one function which deduces that info automagically.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct A;
template<class Ret, class C, class... Args>
struct A<std::function<Ret(C::*)(Args...)>> {
  // use C
}
```

I have no limitations on the version so if there's some new c++20 feature that makes it possible I'm game

Comment: `std::function` is called one kind of a "type erasure" - the original type is gone; `func1` and `func2` are indistinguishable except by results when called. Curious why the source of the `std::function` should make a difference in the first place.

Comment: I'm writing a memoizer that needs to exclude the class argument from the tuple of arguments it uses as a key for the cache. i.e. when the memoized function is called on one object it should be able to get results from a call on another object

Comment: This is not possible as `std::function`s whole purpose is type-erasure as already pointed out. What you can do is to not involve `std::function` until you actually have to store the function object. Would passing a callable to `A` and letting it convert it to a `std::function` after the original type has been resolved work it is a doable approach.

Comment: That works, but restricts users to only being able to pass member function pointers. Which is live-able. I was just poking around gcc source and it looked like I might be able to get at the info somehow but I suppose not

Comment: It's not clear that it would restrict anything, and probably would not. But since we are discussing a scenario that's only in your head only you can answer that.

Comment: True. Also, I should have mentioned another thought. Although type erased, you can still elicit the argument types using decltype(&T::operator()), so I suppose that's what originally made me think there was a way to deduce it, but none of the member functions seem like they can be used to determine the original function type like they can with arguments.